# PCIe Bottleneck and or Slot Issue?

Tags: bandwidth, pci-express

I have a [Supermicro AS-1114S-WN10RT](https://www.supermicro.com/en/Aplus/system/1U/1114/AS-1114S-WN10RT.cfm) with an AMD 7302, 16 core processor, 254 GB DDR4 3200 ECC RAM, striping data to 6 Micron Pro 9300 15 TB RAID 0 drives located in bays 0 & 1 (D:), 4 & 5 (E:), and 6 & 8 (F:). I have two very confusing issues perhaps I can get some help with...

1. There is a 16-lane MXI card ([NI PCIe 8398](https://www.ni.com/en-gb/support/model.pcie-8398.html)) in a dual-slot riser that receives external data that is written to disk(s). We capture an RF signal, process it and send the data to the MXI card. We are trying to write 2 GHz bandwidth to all drives and simultaneously read 1 GHz from drive F:, but at 2.5 GHz (total), the outboard equipment's FIFO buffer fills and all crashes. We have tried different settings and configs, but with no help. I am concerned about the MXI card's location. It is in a [Supermicro RSC-W-66G4 dual riser](https://www.supermicro.com/en/support/resources/riser). It is supposed to be x16, but it straddles two x4 and a one x8 slot. The NVIDIA Quattro is in the lo-pro x16 slot, but if swapped with the MXI card to the dual riser, it will boot, but not output video. As I stare at a stationary underscore on a black screen, I wondered if it was continually enumerating or not outputting video. I set BIOS to onboard graphics and it indeed booted, but I still cannot move 3 GHz of BW without crashing. Any ideas on where my bottleneck might be?
2. Does anyone know if the RSC-W-66G4 dual riser is electrically a x16 from my description of the MOBO slots? Supermicro just says it is a dual x16...

All thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Presumably as you mention drive F: it is running Windows: you could quickly use something like [HwINFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/) to confirm that the cards in the x16 slots are running x16 electrically.

Comment: On Linux, `lspci -vv` should give you the actual speed. See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495011/how-to-interpret-the-result-of-lspci-vv-with-respect-to-pcie-lanes-and-pcie-2).